# Magento how to make my own admin based custom template?

Tags: templates, magento-1.7

I am newbie to the magento. I want to develop my own custom template in magento. Where I would like to have some custom settings from admin panel to change the looks of the theme like change colour or to upload logo etc.. So can someone kindly tell me is there any documentation available or any referenced link? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator

Near the bottom you have the Magento System Configuration section, with this you can create a module to handle all your admin settings for your entire site. This is by far the best way to learn how to setup modules, especially complicated ones that involve admin settings.

There will however be plugins for what you want so check on Magento connect first, and there are some free themes for older Magento installs that include similar custom plugins for customizing the themes you can use as a potential reference if you can dig them up (sorry I don't have any examples to hand as I used bought themes to learn from).